# Can I cook duck breast a day before?

Tags: food-safety, duck

I have to serve a 'carpaccio' of roasted duck breast tomorrow, but I'd like to prepare it today. I want to serve the duck breast on room temperature, after cooking it medium rare or medium.

**Can I cook the duck breast today, store it in the fridge overnight and let it come to room temperature tomorrow?**

(I know that technically this isn't carpaccio, as it isn't raw.)

**UPDATE**

It all worked out really well. Thanks for the advice. ;)
[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, you can do that. Simply make sure that the duck isn't at room temperature for too long. 2 hours is the strict limit: you may wish to be more... sensible about it.

I'd suggest slicing straight from the fridge, as it will not only be easier to get thin slices when the meat is firmer, but it will also de-chill quicker.

Comment: Thanks for the tips! I have to take it on a 2 hour car trip after taking it from the fridge. In that case the advice would probably be to A) cook it tonight, B) store it in the fridge, C) ship it to the next location in 1 piece, D) cut and serve right away. Am I right?

Comment: I would certainly put it in a cooler with a ice pack for the car ride. I would also cut fresh at your destination like you are thinking. Once you cut it you greatly increase the surface area and it will warm up a lot faster.

Comment: Did exactly that, see the updated question for the result!

Comment: Looks great, well done.